# many instances of \DeclareSymbolFont leads to odd behavior

Tags: fonts, symbols

By random chance in a large document of mine I discovered that having many instances of `\DeclareSymbolFont` can lead to strange output. For example the following document, which includes several cobbled together hacks from TeXSE, produces no warnings or errors but changes a script F to a fraktur F if followed by `\smash`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[only,trianglelefteqslant]{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[frak=euler]{mathalpha}

%%% better curly braces from Computer Modern
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
%\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{CMsymbols}{"66}{CMlargesymbols}{"08}
%\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathopen}{CMsymbols}{"67}{CMlargesymbols}{"09}

%%% better hat symbol, and check
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
%\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}
%\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

%%% borrow \lhook and \rhook from libertinust1math
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{libertinust1mathex}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{libsymbols}{LS2}{libertinust1mathsym}{m}{n}


\begin{document}
% incorrect
$\mathscr{F}_x\smash{M} \mathfrak{p}$

% correct
$\mathscr{F}_x M \mathfrak{p}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm obviously not actually using `\smash` like this; it's just to show the issue (originally this came up with a custom macro involving `\smash`).

If any of the packages or `\DeclareSymbolFont` lines are commented out, the output is as expected. Similarly if the `\mathfrak{p}` is removed. Of course, these packages make a lot of font declarations. Note that `mathalpha` cannot be loaded before `kpfonts` since the latter would overwrite the `\mathscr` definition of the former.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I know somewhat recently there was a kernel change involving allocation of math fonts, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

---

simpler MWE to help tracing

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{abc1}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc2}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc3}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc4}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc5}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc6}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc7}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc8}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abc9}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{abca}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathscr{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathfrak{U}{euf}{m}{n}


\def\x#1{\showthe\textfont14 }
\begin{document}
% incorrect
\x0
$\mathscr{F}_x
\hbox{$M\x1$\x2}
 \mathfrak{p}\x3$
\x4

% correct
$\mathscr{F}_x M \mathfrak{p}$
\x5

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Right, I'm familiar with that. But shouldn't that produce a warning or error if I've defined too many? My thinking was that the kernel change "fixed" this somehow (I remember the phrase "dynamic allocation"). Also, why does it only change the font sometimes, like in my example above?

Comment: Indeed, the example runs fine with TL2020, but not with TL2021.

Comment: @egreg I also tried changing the `localmathalphabets` counter to no effect

Comment: The change was in the November 2021 release ([ltnews34](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews34.pdf))

Comment: You're reaching the limit of 16 math groups and somehow the “fix” kicks in. If I comment out the last `\DeclareSymbolFont` declaration, the output is as expected.

Comment: Yes I mentioned that in the post. I know the issue has to do with too many fonts, but I'd like to know if it's supposed to produce an error, as well as why the `\smash` has anything to do with the different outputs

Comment: By the way, your call of `stmaryrd` does nothing at all, besides using up a math group.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. In my actual document I am taking more commands from stmaryrd. I will update the post so that loading it is meaningful

Comment: If you do `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}` it magically works.

Comment: Hmm strange, thanks for investigating. The ltnews doc suggests you'd want a higher value, not lower

Comment: This looks to be essentially https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1028 except the fix rolled out for that doesn't cover this case

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1101

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for looking into it. Do you have insight regarding egreg's observation that the issue disappears after `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}`?

Comment: oh sure setting that to 0 disables the local alphabet feature, but I'm not sure yet why the fix done for 1028 doesn't work here, it's deep in the latex font code so can't really trace during the day, this is tricky stuff:-) ,the fix is probably simple, essentially `\let\stopmessingwithfonts=\relax` but it's a matter of which command to disable and where....