Mysterious symbols appearing in very special context
I have a weird output (weird symbols instead of Enc when calling \mathsf{Enc} in a very specific case:

This occurs only if I load all these 3 packages at once:

calrsfs
stmaryrd
zx-calculus

This is very mysterious to me, any idea what is happening here?
MWE:
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{calrsfs} % Replace \mathcal with different more "cursive" font
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n} % \pazocal is now the old \mathcal

\usepackage{tikz}
% Bug occurs if BOTH zx-calculus and stmaryrd are loaded
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{zx-calculus}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  I expect to read $k \gets \mathsf{Enc}(k, m)$ but I get:
  
$k \gets \mathsf{Enc}(k,
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(txt.base)]
  \node[name=txt,inner sep=0pt] {$m$}; % m must be in math mode for the bug to occur
  \node[overlay,name=annot,font=\tiny,fill=orange!10!white] at (1.5cm,0){Message $m \in \pazocal{M}$};
  \draw[overlay,->] (annot) -- (txt);a
\end{tikzpicture}
)$
\end{frame}
\end{document}


use \setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0} before the frame or in the preamble.

@UlrikeFischer whao, seems to work, thanks, but what is this dark magic?

@UlrikeFischer hmm we really should fix this

Even more mysterious ^^

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689560/208544 and https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1101, which I see Ulrike just updated
